# How to show multiple things as one in a list

Tags: python, list

I am coding a text based adventure game and I am currently working on an inventory system this is the code I have:

```
Inventory=[]

Combat code
A=random.randint(1, 10)
B=random.randint(1, 10)
If a=b:
  Print('enemy dropped wheat')
  Additem('wheat')


Def additem(item):
  Inventory.append(item)

For I in inventory:
  Print(i)
```

I want to make it so that  if I had two wheat it would print 2 wheat not wheat wheat

The code I tried is:

```
inventory=[]

def additem(item):
  Inventory.append(item)

def removeitem(item):
  Inventory.remove

Additem('wheat')
Additem('wheat')

for wheat in inventory: 
  removeitem('wheat')
  Additem(wheat + 'wheat')

For I in inventory:
  Print(i)
```

I expected it to print:
2 wheat
but it printed:
Wheatwheat
Wheatwheatwheat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
# inventory = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
for i in set(inventory): 
    print(inventory.count(i), i) 
>> 2 a
>> 1 b
>> 1 c
```

As a side note, I think you would highly benefit from using a dictionary as your inventory data structure, since it would allow you to add a counter to each item:

```
inventory = {} # = {'wheat': 1, 'arrow': 50...}
def AddItem(item):
    try:
        inventory['item']+= 1
    except KeyError: # the item is new in the inventory
        inventory['item'] = 1
```

Comment: That is not the output your code produces.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dict instead of list, so you can track the item and its quantity ?

```
inventory = {}

def additem(item):
    if item not in inventory:
        inventory[item] = 1
        return
    inventory[item] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
inventory = ["wheat", "wheat", "apple"] 

count = inventory.count("wheat")
```

take that to a print statement as followed:

```
print(f" you now have {count} wheats in your inventory")
```

You could also customize "inventory elements" to be printed with other elements counted in the future.